# Having both atime and noatime on Samba server

Tags: linux, backup, samba

I'm looking to improve my current setup:

I have a samba server (debian), that share a folder located in an ext4 partition, mounted with `relatime` option.

I'm using the files access time for various reasons on my windows and linux clients, and it's working well.

Now I'm regularly making a backup of that folder (with rsync), but, as you have guessed, that reset all the access times to the current time.

I tried many solution, but I think I've exhausted everything I could find...

Any ideas on how I could read those files to backup them without updating the acces time ? The solution I'm using is `mount -o remount,noatime /mnt/hdd` before each backup, and the opposite once the backup is done.

Thanks by advance :)

Comment: Maybe to rely on atime is the sole problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why go with complicated stuff when rsync already has a command line option for this?

From the man page:

```
       --atimes, -U             preserve access (use) times
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't think rsync could do that, I tested and it works, thanks, but the exact option was `--noatime` for my version of rsync